# Spring - migrando de MVC para Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful

Eu fiz um CRUD com Spring Boot, MVC, Security e outros módulos do Spring. Para o front-end usei Thymeleaf. Aparentemente está tudo funcionando, mas na descrição do problema pede "A aplicação deverá conter algumas APIs Rest para o consumo externo: cadastro e consulta de usuários e recursos".

O que devo alterar na minha aplicação? 
mudar de @Controller para @RestController?
os retornos dos métodos das controllers podem continuar retornando ModelAndView e String ou tem que retornar ResponseEntity?
O front-end pode continuar com Thymeleaf?
O que exatamente tem que fazer o consumo externo da API Rest? Só responder a requisição em JSON para o postman?

Comment: Olá bom dia leo, sim meu caro @RestController, ModelAndView não porque agora vc não terá uma View, a Api será consumida por qualquer client então JSP, JSF, PHP, Postman, e ou até uma aplicação Web Spring +Thymeleaf, HTML + Jq, quem consumir terá que indicar o end-point ex http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios o retorno pode ser um JSON mais pode ser um XML, Texto ..... isto é negociável, vá em frente que vc esta perto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está complicando um pouco o requisito. Ao pedir:

> "A aplicação deverá conter algumas APIs Rest para o consumo externo: cadastro e consulta de usuários e recursos".

Não quer dizer que precisa usar o mesmo Controller de tela para isto. Os Controllers existentes, que retornam `ModelAndView`, continuam da mesma forma como estão hoje.

O que você pode fazer é **criar um novo** Controller, no caso, um `RestController` (ou mais de um, se achar melhor).

Ele ficará exclusivamente responsável para atender a estes consumos externos, podendo assim definir o formato de saída (Json), segurança, versionamento da API, endereço de acesso diferente, etc, sem interferir nos Controllers existentes.

Naturalmente, o código de `Service` e e `Repository` serão compartilhados internamente entre os Controllers e RestControllers, para evitar duplicação de código e etc.